# Filename cannot be empty in

Tags: php, file, upload

A few weeks ago I had this code to upload a file to my database , but now does not work

the input:

```
 <input type="file" name="archivo" accept=".doc, .pfd, .docx"/>
```

the .php to upload the file (the connection to the database is made)

```
 $archivo = $_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"]; 
 $tamanio = $_FILES["archivo"]["size"];
 $tama    = $_FILES["archivo"]["size"];
 $tipo    = $_FILES["archivo"]["type"];
 $nombre  = $_FILES["archivo"]["name"];
 $titulo  = $_POST["titulo"];

 if ( $archivo != "none" )
 {
    $fp = fopen($archivo, "rb");
    $contenido = fread($fp, $tamanio);
    $contenido = addslashes($contenido);
    fclose($fp); 

    $qry = "INSERT INTO archivos VALUES 
            (0,'$nombre','$Nombre','$tama','$contenido','$tipo')";

    mysql_query($qry) or die('Consulta fallida: ' . mysql_error());

    if(mysql_affected_rows($link) > 0)
       print "Se ha guardado el archivo en la base de datos.";
    else
       print "NO se ha podido guardar el archivo en la base de datos.";
 }
 else
    print "No se ha podido subir el archivo al servidor";
```

Comment: "does not work" is a pretty vague description of your problem. Do you get any error messages (either on screen or in logs)? Have you done any debugging?

Comment: submit your full html code

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can use `fopen`, `fread` etc to do this.  The error is telling you that.  You need to use `move_uploaded_file` like so to shift that file from the user to the server.

```
  if (!move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],$target_path))
    return '_err_failed';
```

Answer (score -1):

Where show the error?? In the insert? If you say that in the past it worked,  maybe the structure of the table changed.

Comment: Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: Filename cannot be empty in /home/u963604205/public_html/PHP/CV_guardar.php on line 32

Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/u963604205/public_html/PHP/CV_guardar.php on line 33

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/u963604205/public_html/PHP/CV_guardar.php on line 35

The structure of the table has not changed

Answer (score -1):

You have a button to browse the file.  You need another one to post the form.  Something like

```
echo "<input $class type='submit' value='submit' name='$name' id='$name'>"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help , the button for sending this in html form , but that's not the problem why not put it on.

Comment: That is why it would have been nicer for you to post the complete thing. :-)